# Is it possible to assignment the variable of one list to the variable of another list?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, realm

I have multiple **EditText** and I want to save each user input in the **RealmObject()**. I have created a variable in the **RealmObject()** for each **EditText**.

My RealmObject():

```
open class myObject : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    private var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    var b1 = ""
    var b2 = ""
    var b3 = ""
    var b4 = 0
    var b5 = 0
}
```

My Activity:

```
val myObject = myRealmObject()

myObject.b1 = a1EditText.text.toString()
myObject.b2 = a2EditText.text.toString()
myObject.b3 = a3EditText.text.toString()
myObject.b4 = a4EditText.text.toString().toInt()
myObject.b5 = a5EditText.text.toString().toInt()
```

It is easy to use *If Statement* to check if it's not null:

```
if (a1EditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    myObject.b1 = it.toString()
}
```

... but as you can see, the code will become bulky, especially if I add more variables in the object. Is there any way to assign them like:

*listOf(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5)* = *listOf(a1EditText, a2EditText, a3EditText, a4EditText, a5EditText)*.

I have just started programming in Kotlin. Kindly walk me through this.

Comment: What do you mean by ```to their corresponding variable ```? What your object look like?

Comment: @aiqency Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I have updated my question.